# Error parsing Es6 jsx to js React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I trying to work with react. I have the next code :

**index.js**

```
var Btn = require('./components/Btn.jsx');



    var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            console.log("here with me");
            ReactDOM.render(<Btn>, document.getElementbyId('app'))
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        },
    };

    app.initialize();
```

I have the next node_modules instaled:

- Babel
- Babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
- Babel-preset-env
- Babel-cli
- babel-preset-env
- babel-preset-es2017
- babel-preset-react

Mi .babelrc

```
{ "presets": ["env"] }
```

When I run the comand for whath and compile the jsx to js I have the next

```
$ babel --presets env js/src --watch --out-dir js/dist    
SyntaxError: js/src/index.js: Unexpected token (10:24)
       8 |     initialize: function() {
       9 |         console.log("here with me");
    > 10 |         ReactDOM.render(<Btn/>, document.getElementbyId('app'))
         |                         ^
      11 |     },
      12 |
      13 |     onDeviceReady: function() {
```

I really find about this and try a lot of things but i don't undestand what happen, in each tutorial that i see the sintax is correct and all works good.  I hope that this can be something stupid and I can't found it. Can Anyone explain to me What can i do? or how.

Comment: I think it has to do with transpiling react element. Add "transform-react-jsx" plugin to your .babelrc file

Comment: Sorry, How can i do that? Only add this item to the array?

Comment: Like this:
```"plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx"]
  ]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `babel-preset-react`, try adding this to your .babelrc `{"presets": ["react", "es2017"], }` check this link for the format [.babelrc](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc)

Comment: Thanks for answer. yap! this was an error, but it's not the error from the console, i fix that and the console still showing the same "unexpect token"

Comment: since you have `babel-preset-react`, try adding this to your .babelrc `{"presets": ["react", "es2017"], }` check this link for the format https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Comment: Your comment was the asnwer for my problem. very thanks. How can I mark this comment as my asnwer ?